# Setting Chainlink Keystore Password in Docker-Compose

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to spin up a chainlink node using docker-compose and am running into this error:

`error authenticating keystore: No password provided`

I didn't see an environment variable to set this password. The tutorial (https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/#set-the-remote-database_url-config) uses docker and exec directly into the container to set this based on a prompt. Anyone know a solution that doesn't require manual input when bringing up the container?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

x-logging:
  &default-logging
  options:
    max-file: '1'
    compress: 'false'
  driver: local

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres_data: {}

services:
  chainlink-node:
    image: smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.8
    container_name: chainlink
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL}
      ETH_CHAIN_ID: ${ETH_CHAIN_ID}
      ETH_URL: ${ETH_URL}
      ETH_HTTP_URL: ${ETH_HTTP_URL}
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PW}@postgres:5432/${CHAINLINK_DB_NAME}
      MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS: "${MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS}"
      LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: "${LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS}"
      CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT: "${CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT}"
      SECURE_COOKIES: "${SECURE_COOKIES}"
      GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED: "${GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED}"
      ALLOW_ORIGINS: "${ALLOW_ORIGINS}"
    expose:
      - 6688
    ports:
      - "6688:6688"
networks:
      - monitor-net
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging: *default-logging
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    container_name: postgres
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "max_connections=1000", "-c", "shared_buffers=256MB", "-c", "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER:-username}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PW:-password}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${CHAINLINK_DB_NAME:-chainlink-db}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    expose:
 - 5432
    logging: *default-logging
```

And my .env file

```
DB_USER=<username>
DB_PW=<password>
CHAINLINK_DB_NAME=chainlink-db
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=4
ETH_URL=wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/<>
ETH_HTTP_URL=https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<>
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*\" > ~/chainlink-rinkeby/.env
```

EDIT:

After some messing around I found a configuration for the docker-compose.yml file which allowed the chainlink container to start in a stable state.

```
services:
  chainlink-node:
    image: smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.8
    container_name: chainlink
    command: ["local", "n", "-p", "/chainlink/password", "-a", "/chainlink/api"]
    volumes:
      - ./passwords:/chainlink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chainlink node requires different credentials to initialize. These are the `key-store password`, which is needed to create and access the network-related wallets (`primary` & `emergency`) and the `API-credentails` with which you can reach the graphical user interface (GUI) of the Chainlink node.

These credentials are queried during initialization and entered manually when the Chainlink node is started for the first time. If the chainlink node is started in `detached mode` (`-d` flag) or as a `docker-compose` file, these credentials must be mounted as volumes and added as arguments/commands.

With Docker-compose you have different ways to integrate those credentials in order to enable initialisation. I would recommend the following steps:

1. create the file `keystore password`:
   Please ensure that you have minimum 3 capital letters

```
echo "my_wallet_password" > ~/.chainlink-rinkeby/.password
```

2. create the API credentials:

```
echo "user@example.com" > ~/.chainlink-rinkeby/.api
```

```
echo "password" >> ~/.chainlink-rinkeby/.api
```

3. adjust the `docker-compose.yml`:

You now need to mount both files (`.api` & `.password`) by adding `.chainlink-rinkeby` as a `volume` and set those credentials as arguments (`command:`)

```
chainlink-node:
    image: smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.8
    container_name: chainlink
    command: ["-p /chainlink/.password","-a /chainlink/.api"]
    volumes:
      - ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL}
      ETH_CHAIN_ID: ${ETH_CHAIN_ID}
      ETH_URL: ${ETH_URL}
      ETH_HTTP_URL: ${ETH_HTTP_URL}
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PW}@postgres:5432/${CHAINLINK_DB_NAME}
      MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS: "${MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS}"
      LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: "${LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS}"
      CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT: "${CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT}"
      SECURE_COOKIES: "${SECURE_COOKIES}"
      GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED: "${GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED}"
      ALLOW_ORIGINS: "${ALLOW_ORIGINS}"
    expose:
      - 6688
    ports:
      - "6688:6688"
```

In addition you find here the official Chainlink documentation related to this topic: https://docs.chain.link/docs/miscellaneous/